# Is it possible to add shaders to windows in Wayland's rendering pipelines?

Tags: x11, wayland

Considering not all X client programs respect (or are aware of) systemwide palette settings and other accessibility options, it'd be beneficial to be able to insert extra shader steps between the window texture and the on-screen rendering. Does the Wayland compositor or the window manager provide a mechanism for that?